Is MomentumCombine the inverse of ExpandScalarProduct?
My question (perhaps naive) is the following: The documentation says that MomentumCombine is the inverse operation of MomentumExpand and ExpandScalarProduct; if I calculate
SPD[p-k, p-k] // ExpandScalarProduct

I get

SPD[k, k] - 2 SPD[k, p] + SPD[p, p]


Now, what I want to do is the inverse operation, that is, start from SPD[k, k] - 2 SPD[k, p] + SPD[p, p] and get SPD[p-k, p-k]. According to the documentation, I should use MomentumCombine, but when I use it, what I get is SPD[k, k-2p] + SPD[p, p], not SPD[p-k, p-k] (even if applied twice, it gives the same result). How is it possible to get SPD[p-k, p-k] starting from SPD[k, k] - 2 SPD[k, p] + SPD[p, p]?
Of course I could do it by hand, but my expressions are so huge that doing it this way is impossible.
Thanks in advance.

This would appear to be a question for FeynCalc developers or users.
